# How to append data into a partitioned table in bulk, overriding ingestion time partitioning

Tags: google-bigquery

The target table has ingestion time partitioning (`PARTITION BY DATE(_PARTITIONTIME)`). Logging information is flowing into this table.

I'd like to load historical logging data having the same schema and have it be partitioned based on the date portion of a specific `TIMESTAMP` column. I.e., I'd like to override the *mechanism* of the ingestion time partitioning while retaining the data type of the partition id.

When I try to load the data with `bq load`, `bq` complains that the partitioning is incompatible:

```
bq --project_id=myProj \
load \
        --time_partitioning_field=span.endTime \
        --time_partitioning_type=DAY \
        --source_format=PARQUET \
        myDataset.test_junk \
        gs://mybucket/test/export-*.parquet
```

The result:

`E0419 17:06:29.304003 140704289732224 bq_utils.py:244] BigQuery error in load operation: Error processing job 'myProj:bqjob_r4bd44de633ecd32f_000001879b5714b9_1': Incompatible table partitioning specification. Expects partitioning specification interval(type:day), but input partitioning specification is interval(type:day,field:span.endTime)`

Is there any easier way to accomplish my goal than writing custom code per [this stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63628885/how-can-i-migrate-an-ingestion-time-partitioned-table-between-regions-in-bigquer)?

Comment: As mentioned in this [document](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/partitioned-tables#limitations), for Time-unit column-partitioned tables column must be a top-level field. You cannot use a leaf field from a RECORD (STRUCT) as the partitioning column.You can refer to this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-storage-parquet#loading_parquet_data_into_a_new_table) to Load Parquet data into a partitioned table. Let me know if it's helpful or not?

Comment: @PrajnaRaiT I had hoped because of the very existence of ingestion time partitioning (i.e. partitioning based on something other than the row content) that overriding the existing partitioning might be possible at load time. However, your comment makes me think that even if I could fix the above error, I would immediately run into the nested field issue. I think I have to loop over the rows in Python and use the '$yyyymmdd' table name suffix syntax to force each row into the correct partition (based on the value of `span.endTime`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TL/DR: I had to use the `{table}${partition}` syntax to dump and load partitions individually.

I came to the conclusion that there was no way to do a single dump and a single load that would work given the constraints:

- Source and destination tables are both partitioned using ingestion time.
- Records loaded in the destination table must have the correct ingestion time, that is, the original ingestion time in the source table.
- Data must be appended to the destination table.

Additional constraints:

- Source and destination tables in different regions.
- Schema uses nested data structure that failed to be automatically loaded properly using anything other than JSON format.

I could have used a programmatic API, but I wound up writing a program to generate shell scripts to use `bq`, `gcloud`, and `gsutil` to dump and load all the partitions individually.

Commands wound up looking like:

```
# Set project for source
gcloud config set project {source_project}

# Extract partition 20220325
bq extract --location {source_region} \
--destination_format NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON \
--quiet=true \
--format=pretty \
--compression GZIP \
'{source_project}:{dataset}.{table}$20220325' \
gs://{source_bucket}/dump.20220325.json.gz

# ... and similar for the rest of the partitions ...

# Copy all the dumps from source to destination region
gsutil cp -r gs://{source_bucket} gs://{destination_bucket}

# Set project for destination
gcloud config set project {destination_project}

# Load partition (20220325) into destination table
bq load --location={destination_region} \
--source_format=NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON \
--quiet=true \
--format=pretty \
--autodetect=false \
'{destination_project}:{dataset}.{table}$20220325' \
gs://{destination_bucket}/dump.20220325.json.gz

# ... and similar for the rest of the partition dumps ...
```

I was surprised to run into problems using Parquet: the loads would fail with "Provided Schema does not match Table". It may have been possible to use some flag to get a perfect schema match, but since JSON worked as shown above, I wasn't motivated to dig too deeply.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in this [document](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-storage-parquet#loading_parquet_data_into_a_new_table):

`--time_partitioning_type:` Enables time-based partitioning on a table and sets the partition type. Possible values are HOUR, DAY, MONTH, and YEAR. This flag is optional when you create a table partitioned on a DATE, DATETIME, or TIMESTAMP column. The default partition type for time-based partitioning is DAY. You cannot change the partitioning specification on an existing table.

`--time_partitioning_field:` The DATE or TIMESTAMP column used to create a partitioned table. If time-based partitioning is enabled without this value, an ingestion-time partitioned table is created.

**For example:**

The command that loads data from `gs://mybucket/mydata.parquet` into a new ingestion-time partitioned table named `mytable` in `mydataset`.

```
    bq load \
    --source_format=PARQUET \
    --time_partitioning_type=DAY \
    mydataset.mytable \
    gs://mybucket/mydata.parquet
```

The command that loads data from `gs://mybucket/mydata.parquet` into a partitioned table named `mytable` in `mydataset`. The table is partitioned on the `mytimestamp` column.

```
    bq load \
    --source_format=PARQUET \
    --time_partitioning_field mytimestamp \
    mydataset.mytable \
    gs://mybucket/mydata.parquet
```

For more information you can refer to this [document](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-storage-parquet#loading_parquet_data_into_a_new_table).

You can refer to this document about the [limitations](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/partitioned-tables#limitations) of types of partitioned tables.